# Display text after typing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/juqc24ux/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your number here..." id="resultTextBox">

$('#resultTextBox').keypress(function() {
    alert($('#resultTextBox').val());
}) // end keypress
```

I don't know what I'm getting wrong. I want to obtain the value of the text box after I press the button. This does not happen, however.

After I press '1', an empty alert pops up and then '1' gets entered into the keyboard. Then, after I press, say, '2', an alert with '1' pops up.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it in a sense that after I press '1', it gets into the text box and then it's being shown in the alert? I'm pretty sure it has to do with the priority of executing the code, just I'm not sure how to fix this..

UPDATE: Some of you pointed that 'keyup' works. But why does it work and keypress doesn't?

Comment: `KeyPress` doesn't work because it's when the key goes down, essentially registering the event before the text is actually entered into the box. `KeyUp` is after that even fires, that's why it will show up then.

Comment: See my updated answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard.

[keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

Use `keyup` instaed. Like below.

```js
$('#resultTextBox').keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your number here..." id="resultTextBox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Keypress executes *before* the letter gets entered into the textbox. Think of the process this way:

1. `keypress` event fires
2. Key does what it normally does, in this case enter the number 1 into the textbox
3. `keyup` event fires

That's why your alert comes up empty after entering 1 and only displays '1' after entering 2 afterwards. It can only alert what was present in the textbox at the instant you press the key *before* anything else gets the chance to happen, including entering a number in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your number here..." id="resultTextBox">
```

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#resultTextBox').keyup(function() {
   alert($('#resultTextBox').val());
  }) // end keypress
});
</script>
```

Or another method if you want

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your number here..."  id="enternum">
<input type="text" placeholder="show result" id="resultTextBox">

   <script>

 $('#enternum').keypress(function() {

   $('#resultTextBox').val($('#enternum').val());
    }) 
 </script>
```